# Downloading a file via an Anchor Tag

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have set up downloading of a zip file via an anchor tag as follows.

```
<a href="download/sample.zip">sample.zip</a>
```

The file download works fine if the file is present in the download directory then a file download dialog opens and the user can download the file.

If the file is not present then it results in a 404 error if the file is present and the user has to login again.

Is there a way to cause this download to happen in a new page or check the existence of this file in javascript and control whether the download functionality should be not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the link open in a new tab:

```
<a href="download/sample.zip" target="_blank">sample.zip</a>
```